# no space beetwen values txt java

Tags: java, txt

Code works fine, except one problem. After increasing salary the spaces beetwen values disapears and then my programm doesn't work well.

```
Joe 2022/04/05 HR-Manager44200
Steve 2022/04/06 Admin 100000
```

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.print("Name of employee : "); 
String pID = console.nextLine(); System.out.print("Allowance : "); 
replenish = console.nextInt();    
File originalFile = new File("worker.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(originalFile));

    File tempFile = new File("tempfile.txt");
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.contains(pID)) {
            String strCurrentSalary = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" "));
            if (strCurrentSalary != null || !strCurrentSalary.trim().isEmpty()) {
                int replenishedSalary = Integer.parseInt(strCurrentSalary.trim()) + replenish;
                System.out.println("Sum with added : " + replenishedSalary);
                line = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" ")) + replenishedSalary;
            }

        }
        pw.println(line);
        pw.flush();
    }
    pw.close();
    br.close();
```

I want to know where is the problem and why space doesn't adding

Comment: When you use `line.lastIndexOf(" ")` here `line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" "))` it does not include the space, so you need to add +1 to the substring end index `line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" ") +1)` or add a space manually `line = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" ")) + " " + replenishedSalary;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are losing space because `line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" "))` will return a substring up to the last space not including the space so you could add a space after `line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" "))` like below.

```java
line = line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" ")) + " " + replenishedSalary;
```

Also you can use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) to create the line as below.

```java
line = String.format("%s %d",line.substring(0, line.lastIndexOf(" ")),replenishedSalary)
```